Users can't change their 365 passwords when IT admin reset them
I am the IT admin for a school. When I reset an account password in 365 Admin Centre, if I tick the "require user to change their password" option, then after they put the temporary password in and the password they choose on that same dialogue box in the self service password reset portal, they get "your organisation won't allow you to change your password".
The only setting that can be changed in relation to this that I know of is the self-service password reset option in Entra, so I can't work out how to fix this. Any ideas?

The only setting that can be changed in relation to this that I know of is the self-service password reset option in Entra - Is self-service password reset enabled?

Is there a local AD involved?

Self-service password reset is disabled. The school uses AD but it's not synced to MS 365
